# Getting cloudinary default image to work with Django object

Tags: django, url, cloudinary

I'm trying to get Cloudinary default image to show up in my Django template, but it's not working. Each image URL works separately, but when combined, neither works. It goes to the one error.

```
<img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/.../d_{{ id }}/{{ system|lower|cut:' '}}.png" width="250px" onerror='this.onerror = null; this.src=""'/>
```

Comment: Could you please share the full URL (with values expanded) that you are trying to access?

Comment: Thanks, but the 'cloud name', 'resource_type' and 'type' are hidden from the URL - could you share the complete URL we can access? Alternatively, what is the response you receive when you access a complete URL from your side, 400, 404?

Comment: I asked cloudinary and they were able to fix it for me -the problem was that I was not referring to the default image in the right place.